# How to pick a random object with a given probability

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, random

I have an array of type `MyObject`, which itself has a single property (`probability`) of type `Double`.

```
let A = MyObject(probability: 0.33)
let B = MyObject(probability: 0.25)
let C = MyObject(probability: 0.42)
let objects = [A, B, C]
```

How can I draw at random one element from `objects` given the probabilities of the `MyObject` instances that it contains, please?

For example, I expect 25% of the time that the object `B` will be selected.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does your current attempt look like and what is the issue with it?

Comment: Create an array of integers containing 0 to 99, and pick one randomly.

Comment: @Scriptable Messy -- inverting the CDF and mapping indices. Was hoping there would be an efficient method in Swift for this, please.

Comment: In theory, if you draw between 0 and 100 (with a rand()%100), then divide by 100, and check whereas you are between `[0, 0.33]; [0.33, 0.33+0.25]; [0.33+0.25; 1]` should give you the desired result.

Comment: @ElTomato I could generate an array of 1000 elements, containing `(0.33 * 1000.0)` occurrences of `A`, etc. then pick one at random, but this is not the best way to do this type of problem.

Comment: @Larme I guess that could work

Comment: See the linked duplicate question and the accepted answer.  In your case, `let selectedItem = objects[randomNumber(probabilities: [0.33, 0.25, 0.42])]`.  You could even use `map` to extract the probabilities to pass to the function.